# SQL Cluster with different Edition

Tags: sql-server-2012, clustering

Is it possible to join new node SQL in Failover cluster with different Edition?
As example:

Cluster Failover running based on SQL Enterprise Evaluation Edition add a new node based on SQL Standard Edition

Comment: Let us know after you try it.

Answer (score 6):

I've never tried this but I'm reliably informed it is 100% not possible. It is certainly not supported by Microsoft, for good reason, so why would you do it?

> The SQL Server edition you are installing must match across all the
>   nodes in a SQL Server failover cluster. When you add a new node to an
>   existing SQL Server failover cluster, make sure that you specify that
>   the edition matches the edition of the existing failover cluster.

This comes from [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179530.aspx) MSDN link found almost instantly after a quick web search.

Bear in mind there are a few obvious and not-so-obvious functional reasons why you would not want to failover from Enterprise to Standard as some features are not supported in both.

The idea of a clustered environment should be that you maintain integrity of the database environment upon failover, so why compromise that in any way, whether talking about support or features?

Comment: You can edit your answer. It is not possible, the installer will stop you from adding a node that is not the same edition.

Answer (score -3):

This should be possible.

However, do note that some features that are present in Enterprise Editions may not be available in Standard Editions. This can cause severe application issues when a Failover occurs.

I suppose, a Standard edition may be used on an Always-On Secondary Replica where Reporting is offloaded and it does not ideally act as a Failover node. In any case, please test out your solution before taking it forward on Production.