# Sql failover cluster issue with different edition setup ( enterprise with standard)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, clustering

I have come across one client who has setup like this where dba has installed
sql server 2014 instance  with enterprise edition setup on node1 and on node2 he has added mssqlserver 2014 in failover cluster with setup of standard edition .

They have never tested the failover before last night they did the patching on passive node and tried to failover active node( node1 enterprise) to passive( node2 standard) but it got failed and services doesn't come up on both the nodes. In the last they had to remove the node2 from cluster and end up repairing sql services on node1.

May i know the cause of it? can it be due to edition mismatch

setup detail abcdxyz sql instance (enterprise) running on node1
added the node to failover cluster on noode2 with standard setup .

Comment: Does [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/167628/sql-cluster-with-different-edition/167631) answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

to solve the issue do an **edition upgrade of sql server** on the node 2.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/install-windows/upgrade-to-a-different-edition-of-sql-server-setup?view=sql-server-2017

It should not even require the service to be stopped.
At the end you have to restart the node 2